# IntelliJ and M2 repo

Tags: intellij-idea

I have configured Maven in IntelliJ, and the paths are correct to the M2 repo. How do I tell IntelliJ to look at that repo when it needs a dependency in my project?

Comment: In IntelliJ settings, you can specify a repository.

Comment: Is that a Maven project, or you want to add a dependency to a non-maven project from the local repo?

Comment: I have set up Maven in the settings. This is not a Maven project, but an IntelliJ project created from scratch. I just want to access the jars that are already in my .m2 repo.

Comment: I'm not having much success. I managed to put all my .m2/repository as a "library" in my project, but IntelliJ does not discover the jars in there, and does not suggest to resolve dependencies using that local repo. I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you entered dependencies for the jar files you need to use in the pom.xml file of the project? If you haven't, it is normal not to access any libraries in m2 repo from your project.

Answer (score 8):

In Settings > Maven click on Override next to Local repository directory
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven.html

Hope this helps.